# My laptop's fingerprint scanner not detecting even in LSUSB

Tags: drivers, usb, scanner, 21.10, fingerprint-reader

My laptop has a fingerprint scanner and that works well when on windows but when loggedinto ubuntu, the fingerprint scanner is not detected.
This is my *lsusb*

```
the_cactus_knox@Cactus-Knox:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:56a8 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

this is the *lspci* output

```
the_cactus_knox@Cactus-Knox:~$ sudo lspci
[sudo] password for the_cactus_knox: 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b71 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:15.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP LPSS: I2C Controller #2
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SATA AHCI Controller
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 02a8
00:1e.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02aa
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP LPC Premium Controller/eSPI Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SMBus Host Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

What could be the problem here?

And how can I add my fingerprint and use it for logging in??

Comment: Hello. Make and model of the laptop? Kernel version being used?

Comment: @David Hardware model: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ASUSPRO P1440FAC_P1440FA

Comment: Not all fingerprintscanners are supported. I have a HP Envy 17 C1000n and my synaptics  fpscanner is not supported. Hence the question of David.

Comment: I don't know the specifications of my fingerprint sensor but I do know the model number.
My laptop is Asus Pro P1440.

Comment: Some fingerprint readers are PCI devices. If yours falls into this category, then it may appear with `sudo lspci`. If there are zero results still, then you may need to examine whether this is one of the "special" models that routes the fingerprint through the TPM module, making it a Windows-only piece of hardware.

Comment: For Windows it uses a Elantech driver. I cannot fid the model however.

Comment: Look at this Github post; https://github.com/iafilatov/libfprint

Comment: I have made some changes in the question. I have added the lspci output